# Define order of loading classes in Composer autoload

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm using psr4 autoloading to load all classes from a directory, below is what I've done.

```
autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "jframework\\":"vendor/myapp/src/"
    }
 }
```

is there a way, I can load files orderly e.g. if I want to load in this order

```
Bootstrap.php
Core.php
Session.php
Router.php
```

Comment: I believe you can specify certain classes/files to be loaded in a specific order with the `"files"` key. It should maintain the order in which you add them. Not entirely sure tho.

Comment: Not sure I understand the use case. If they are class definitions as the question title states, the order shouldn't matter (that's the whole point of class auto-loading). Are they just regular code files?

Comment: Agree with Gonzalez, with autoloading you shouldn't be worried about it.

Comment: Yes regular code files some contains dependency to another so i should load it one after another

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Composer to tell whether it can be used for this. But this is the use case I've traditionally addressed by creating an initialisation file to act as single entry point. So instead of having `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php;` in every script you could have something like `require __DIR__ . '/config.php;`, in which you'd have `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php;` on top to take care of classes and then `require __DIR__ . '/Bootstrap.php` etc. in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

The whole principle of autoload is that files are looked up when *needed* by code. It also assumes that class files don't have any runtime logic and including class file *only* makes class definition(s) available.

If you have some kind of runtime logic with definitions it's advisable to separate it out for use with autoload.

You could try to make an explicit load procedure that tries to instantiate classes in your preferred order but that won't be too robust long term.

In a nutshell — change to autoload completely or stick with explicit load, don't mix the approaches for the same classes.